# How to pass or set token when click on image in html panel in splunk?

Tags: javascript, xml, visualization, splunk, splunk-query

I want to set or pass value to the token , after clicking on image in HTML panel

Here is my panel code:

```
<form script="my.js">
<row>
<panel>
<html>
<a id="mydivId">
<img src="/static/app/My_app/bck_city.png"/>
</a>
</html>
</panel>
</row>
</form>
```

And after clicking on the image of above panel the below token should set with value
(I want to set token="mytoken", with some value after clicking on the image above)

```
<row>
<panel>
<title>mypanel</title>
<event>
<search>
<query>|makeresults
|eval result=$mytoken$
|table result</query>
<earliest>-15m</earliest>
<latest>now</latest>
</search>
<option name="list.drilldown">none</option>
<option name="refresh.display">progressbar</option>
</event>
</panel>
</row>
```

I also tried setting token value by .js

```
 require(['underscore',
'jquery',
'splunkjs/mvc',
'splunkjs/mvc/utils',
'splunkjs/mvc/tokenutils',
'splunkjs/mvc/simplexml/ready!'], function ($) {
    var utils = require("splunkjs/mvc/utils");
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mydivId").on("click", function (){
    var tokens = mvc.Components.get("default");
    var tokenValue = tokens.get("mytoken");
    tokens.set("mytoken", "cheese");
        });
    });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2fvM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have published an example for you here:

https://github.com/bshuler/splunk_app_for_stackoverflow_questions

but the basics are:

view:

```
<dashboard script="set_token.js">
  <row>
    <panel>
      <title>mytoken = $mytoken$</title>
      <html>
        <a id="mydivId">
        <img src="/static/app/stackoverflow/set_token.jpg"/>
        </a>
      </html>
    </panel>
  </row>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <table>
        <search id="search1">
          <query>| makeresults | eval my_value="$mytoken$"</query>
          <earliest>-15m</earliest>
          <latest>now</latest>
        </search>
        <option name="drilldown">none</option>
      </table>
    </panel>
  </row>
</dashboard>
```

and javascript set_token.js

```
require([
    "splunkjs/mvc",
    "splunkjs/mvc/simplexml/ready!"
], function(mvc) {

    // Get your div
    var my_div = $("#mydivId");

    // Respond to clicks
    my_div.on("click", function(e) {
        var tokens = mvc.Components.get("submitted");
        tokens.set("mytoken", "cheese");
    });

});
```